# How to get getSystemService using myConext

Tags: android

i am doing given below  but it is giving exception unable to instantiate activity

> java.lang.InstantiationException

below is my code>

```
 public class GetDeviceIdActivity extends Activity{

Context myContext;
public GetDeviceIdActivity(Context myContext)
{
    this.myContext = myContext;

}

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: why are you use context? your class is activity

Comment: its my application need . it's running with Activity but not with myContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: @Adb -- to accept his answer you need to actually click the check so that it shows, otherwise he doesn't get credit for the answer.

Comment: i was doing that but a message box shown that you can accept this after 6 minuts.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong, you are already in Activity, you don't need context to get Telephony manager context, Use below code. or instantiate tm in oncreate method. or by using this keyword, or by using activityname.this keyword.

```
    public class GetDeviceIdActivity extends Activity{

     Context myContext;
     public GetDeviceIdActivity(Context myContext)
       {
          this.myContext = myContext;

                }

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```